# A problem on GCD

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, computational-mathematics

I want to calculate $f(n)$ where $f(n)$ is given by

$$f(n) = \sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{n}{gcd(n,i)}$$

and $2\leq n\leq 10^{12}$. Can someone tell me the fastest algorithm to calculate this.

thanks

Comment: Up to $10^{12}$? Is this some sort of contest problem?

Comment: $f$ is a multiplicative function of $n$, and $f(p^r)$ is something like $1+p(p^{2r}-1)/(p+1)$. So I recommend factoring $n$ into prime powers and computing $f$ that way.

Comment: if n=p1^e1*p2^e2 and so then f(n)=f(p1^e1)*f(p2^e2) like this??

Comment: Are people supposed to get outside help on spoj problems?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I totally agree with you but I tried my best to solve this before posting here

Comment: How many calls to f will be made? Going by Gina's answer, which seems to be correct, I think the intention is to use something like the sieve of eratosthenes if the  number of calls is high.

Comment: Yes gina's anwer did the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a given possible value $d$ for $gcd(n,i)$, then we have the number of possible $i$ is $\phi(\frac{n}{d})$. Hence the sum can be rewritten as $\sum\limits_{d|n}\phi(\frac{n}{d})\frac{n}{d}=\sum\limits_{d|n}\phi(d)d$

Hence assuming you factor $n$ into primes somehow, what you can do is this:

Enumerate through all factors. If $n=\prod p_{i}^{a_{i}}$ then each factor have the form $d=\prod p_{i}^{e_{i}}$ for some $0\leq e_{i}\leq a_{i}$

For each possible factor $d=\prod p_{i}^{e_{i}}$ (where all exponent are nonzero-unlike the previous line) you can calculate $\phi(d)d=\prod (p_{i}-1)p_{i}^{2e_{i}-1}$

Of course, the hard part is going to be the factoring. I'm not sure how to do that quick. It might, in the end, be slower than brute force.

Comment: Thank you for the information Gina it worked for me